# Embedding Python into C - can't import method from python module

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, import, embedding

I'm building C application which will be using Python plugins. When trying to call the method from another Python module, the function `PyImport_ImportModule()` seems to imports the module properly, then i try to get the function from this module using `PyObject_GetAttrString()` and all that I get is null.

I already tried using `PyModule_GetDict()` and `PyDict_GetItemString()` to get the method from the module, but the effect was the same.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <python3.6/Python.h>

int main()
{
    PyObject *arg, *pModule, *ret, *pFunc, *pValue, *pMethod, *pDict;
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject *path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
    PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("."));

    pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("test");
    if(pModule == NULL)
    {
        perror("Can't open module");
    }
    pMethod = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "myfun");
    if(pMethod == NULL)
    {
        perror("Can't find method");
    }

    ret = PyEval_CallObject(pMethod, NULL);
    if(ret == NULL)
    {
        perror("Couldn't call method");
    }

    PyArg_Parse(ret, "&d", pValue);
    printf("&d \n", pValue);

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

test.py:

```
def myfun():
  c = 123 + 123
  print('the result is: ', c)

myfun()
```

The result i got is:

```
Can't find method: Success
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I used the gdb debugger the output was:

```
pModule = (PyObject *) 0x7ffff5a96f48
pMethod = (PyObject *) 0x0
```

Comment: Your `pMethod` is `NULL`, and you then try to call it anyway, so that generates a segmentation fault and crashes your program. You should debug what happens before that. Also, do not use `perror`: the python C API does not set `errno`, so using `perror` will get useless messages (in fact in this case it says "Success").

Comment: Thanks but seg fault is not a problem it's a consequence. The problem is, why pMethod is NULL? Before calling pMethod I import the module which gives me "pModule = (PyObject *) 0x7ffff5a96f48" so if the module imports correctly, why the pMethod is not there? --> pMethod = (PyObject *) 0x0

Comment: what does `PyObject_HasAttrString(pModule, "myfun")` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is not wroking because the module being imported is the [`test` built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html), rather than your `test.py` script. This is because you are **appending** the current directory to `sys.path`, so it is checked after every other already existing path in the list. You should **insert it at the beginning** of the list instead, so that it is checked first.

This will work:

```
PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");                                                                                                                                                                     
PyObject *path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");                                                                                                                                                     
PyList_Insert(path, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("."));
```

---

By the way, you should `#include` the Python header before anything else, as stated in the documentation:

> Note: Since Python may define some pre-processor definitions which affect the standard headers on some systems, you must include Python.h before any standard headers are included.